# Как храниться память у URLCache.shared? Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, кэширование, memory

Хотел бы прояснить несколько вещей по поводу `URLCache`. В этого класса есть 2 важных свойства: `memoryCapacity` и `diskCapacity`. В документации описание этих свойств — кот наплакал. Что я пока что понял: `diskCapacity` — сколько памяти диска использовать для `Cache`. Но есть и `memoryCapacity`. То есть получается, что не весь cache сохраняется на диске.
Вопрос #1: Так вот первый вопрос: Где еще хранится `cache`? (может там `cache` процессора, оперативная память или что-то еще. Сори, я плохо разбираюсь в hardware :) )

Второе: В инициализаторе я могу вообще поставить ноль в `diskCapacity`, и `cache` все равно будет работать.

Вопрос #2: В чем разница, хранить `cache` на диске или где-то еще (а где, хотелось бы узнать из первого вопроса :D ). Или другими словами, какие возможности я получаю от того, что храню `cache` на диске?

Третье. Зачастую свойство `currentDiskUsage` ведет себя очень странно и отлично от `currentMemoryUsage` (с которым все, вроде как, понятно): значение `diskUsage` всегда значительно превышает значение у `memoryUsage`, и даже после того, как `memoryUsage` полностью заполнен, и его значение больше не меняется, значение `diskUsage` продолжает расти, пока не дойдет до своего порога и не отчистится.

[image]

Вопрос #3: Зачем занимать все больше и больше места, когда `memoryUsage` уже полон и делать ничего, по крайней мере как я считаю, не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

**Вопрос №1**
Сache процессора, оперативная память, все зависит от аппаратной реализации

**Вопрос №2** разница в скорости доступа + очистка кеша, так например кеш из оперативной памяти очистится после закрытия приложения а вот кеш на диске может пролежать там несколько дней (зависит от настройки системы + кеш может быть очищен при нехватке памяти для других приложений)

**Вопрос №3** Все правильно, когда мы заполним кеш оперативной памяти и/или процессора то часть его вытесняется в доступное пространство (то есть записывается на диск). Кеш будет занимать все доступное ему место пока оно не закончится или не будет ограничено системой. А на вопрос зачем ответ прост - так оно работает. 
[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88) говорит что кеш - это "промежуточный буфер с быстрым доступом, содержащий информацию, которая может быть запрошена с наибольшей вероятностью". Что он собственно и делает. Почитайте про кеширование может вам станет понятней.